# I need to get svn_deff out put between two revisions in php

Tags: php, svn

I tried using this `svn diff -r BEGIN_REVISION:END_REVISION`  in terminal, I get results , But I need a solution in php. I tried this code

```
$svn_blame_array=exec("svn diff -r 125:126 --username abc --password abc753 ",$ret); 
print_r ( $ret );
```

in php. Below error is occurred ,

```
"You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in /var/www/.subversion/servers.
Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? svn: Can't read stdin: End of file found"
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Well, you could just read what it says and do so.. "You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in /var/www/.subversion/servers"

Comment: What does this have to do with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error appears, because the `svn` command is run as the user who runs the webserver process (often called `www-data`). By default subversion will try to cache authentication data into the `~/.subversion` directory of a user (which is `/var/www` for the webserver user on your machine).

If you don't want that, you can try to add the `--no-auth-cache` option to your command.

You may also want to add `--non-interactive`.

Comment: Then you should remove the `--non-interactive` again and see if you get errors or messages again.

Comment: Thank you .This is working , It is really help me if is there any idea svn_diff function to do this